# Redmine installation on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Tags: ruby, rubygems, redmine

I'm trying to install Redmine on Ubuntu 12.04 following [this procedure](http://www.developerof.com/articles/install-redmine).

When I try to initialize Redmine with the command `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate`, I get an error saying: `please install MySQL adapter.... Can't activate mysql(~> 2.8.1) , already activated MySQL-2.9.1'...`.

I'm stuck at this stage I need help please.

Comment: [1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826036/cant-activate-mysql2-0-3-6-already-activated-mysql2-0-3-2-in-rails-3-1

Comment: Should be deleted as it  is very old and issue difficult to reproduce